# Example: Velocity Verlet reduced accuracy

Tags: ode, time-integration, molecular-dynamics

Velocity Verlet is often held to far more accurate than forward Euler while being no more expensive. Technically, this requires some degree of regularity on the potential. But, is there a convincing example of a potential for which Velocity Verlet will be no more accurate than forward Euler?

Comment: Did you make some experiments, integrate a 2-body system with Euler, Heun (with double step size) and Verlet using the same number of function evaluations?